# Is the following true: if $X = Y$ in distribution, then $XI_{\{|X| < a\}} = YI_{\{|Y| < a\}}$ in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Is the following true: if $X = Y$ in distribution, then $XI_{\{|X| <
>  a\}} = YI_{\{|Y| < a\}}$ in distribution, where $I$ denotes the
>   indicator function on the given set, and where $a$ is a fixed constant

I have to prove that $\mathbb{P}\{XI_{\{|X| < a\}} \in A\} = \mathbb{P}\{YI_{\{|Y| < a\}} \in A\}$ for any Borel set of the reals, but I honestly have no clue how to prove it. The statement seems intuitively true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued, take any $b\in \mathbb{R}$; then it is enough to show that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X I_{|X|<a} \leq b) = \mathbb{P}(Y I_{|Y|<a} \leq b) .
$$
We have
$$
\mathbb{P}(X I_{|X|<a} \leq b)  = \mathbb{P}(-a \leq X \leq a, X \leq b ) + \mathbb{P}(|X| > a) \chi_{\{b\geq 0\}} = \\ 
\mathbb{P}(-a \leq X \leq \min\{a,b\})  + \mathbb{P}(|X| > a) \chi_{\{b\geq 0\}} = \\ 
\mathbb{P}(-a \leq Y \leq \min\{a,b\})  + \mathbb{P}(|Y| > a) \chi_{\{b\geq 0\}} = \\
\mathbb{P}(Y I_{|Y|<a} \leq b)  
$$
since $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.